# Records not showing in order

Tags: php, laravel, twig, octobercms

I have built a custom plugin in OctoberCMS and i have successfully implemented the Reorder controller.

The only problem now is that the records do not display on the frontend in the order i have set in the backend.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
{% for course in record.courses %}
          <div class="col-md-4 mt-3 mb-4">
              <a href="{{ course.slug }}">
              <div class="box-new">
                <div class="box-header" style="background:url('{{ course.banner.path() }}');">
                    <div class="box-meta">
                        <p class="box-meta-category">{{ course.category.title }}</p>
                        <hr class="box-line">
                        <p class="box-meta-title">{{ course.title }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-course-details">
                    <ul id="box-course-details">
                        <li><strong>Valid</strong> {{ course.valid_for }}</li>
                        <li><strong>Duration</strong> {{ course.duration }}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </a>
                <div class="action">
                    <a href="/course/{{ course.slug }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-new">View Course</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the [Reorder](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/reorder#introduction) you implemented is using a [Sortable](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/traits#sortable) trait. If so, this will simply set the `sort_order` columns in your database, but it doesn't automatically sort by that on the front end. From your code above it looks like you are using a relationship where your `record` hasMany `courses`. Update your relationship definition in whatever your `record` model is like this:

```
public $hasMany = [
    'courses' => ['Foo\Bar\Models\Course', 'order' => 'sort_order']
];
```